# Zend Framework: Saving complete page to a file

Tags: zend-framework, layout, save, render

I need to add the main navigation/header from my Zend based site onto the top of a third party product. The third party product will allow me to include any file(s) on the server into their layouts. My thought was I would run a cron that would save the header part of my Zend layout to a hard coded html file each night. Then just read in the appropriate file on the third part.

So I tried:

$htmlcontent = $this->view->render('file.phtml');

then saving $htmlcontent to a file. It saves out everything from file.phtml correctly but excludes the layout/header, which the part I really need. How would I go about saving everything generated ( including layout) to a file.

thanks
summer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view script is just a part of the whole layout. In a normal Zend Framework setup, you will have one layout  in which your view scripts (eg, file.phtml) in your case. The layout file will look like this:

```
   <html>
      <body>
          <div>My header here</div>
          <?php echo $this->layout()->content; ?>
          <div>I have a footer here.</div>
      </body>
   </html>
```

**$this->layout()->content** will hold your  view script, according to the page you are in (eg, file.phtml when your call fileAction()).

So, to access the full HTML of your page, you have two options:

1. Use the good old [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and get the complete rendered HTML to a string with http request.

   ```
   $htmlcontent = file_get_contents('http://yourdomain/index/file');
   ```
2. Get the layout instance of the Zend Framework, assign content to it, and render it to a string as follows:

   ```
    $layout = $this->_helper->layout->getLayoutInstance();
    $layout->content = $this->view->render('file.phtml');
    $htmlcontent =  $layout->render();
   ```

Comment: Thanks! The $this->_helper->layout->getLayoutInstance(); is exactly what I was missing!